# GC Deployment Manager install PHP with Jinja template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, config, google-deployment-manager

I want do deploy a PHP app via the Google Cloud Deployment Manager. After an instance has been created, PHP (and some other Linux packages) should be installed on the VM. Is this possible within the template file? Or do I have to create a custom VM image?

I only managed to create the VM, but didn't find anything on how to automatically install packages.

```
{% set COMPUTE_URL_BASE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/' %}
{% set BASE_NAME = env['deployment'] + '-' + env['name'] %}

{% macro GlobalComputeUrl(project, collection, name) -%}
{{ COMPUTE_URL_BASE }}projects/{{ project }}/global/{{ collection }}/{{ name }}
{%- endmacro %}

{% macro ZonalComputeUrl(project, zone, collection, name) -%}
{{ COMPUTE_URL_BASE }}projects/{{ project }}/zones/{{ zone }}/{{ collection }}/{{ name }}
{%- endmacro %}

resources:
- name: {{ BASE_NAME }}
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties['zone'] }}
    machineType: {{ ZonalComputeUrl(env['project'], properties['zone'], 'machineTypes', 'e2-micro') }}
    metadata:
      items:
        - key: gce-container-declaration
          value: |
            {{ imports[properties['containerManifest']]|indent(12) }}
    disks:
      - deviceName: boot
        type: PERSISTENT
        autoDelete: true
        boot: true
        initializeParams:
          diskName: {{ BASE_NAME }}-disk
          sourceImage: {{ GlobalComputeUrl('cos-cloud', 'images', properties['containerImage']) }}
    networkInterfaces:
      - accessConfigs:
          - name: external-nat
            type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
        network: {{ GlobalComputeUrl(env['project'],  'networks', 'default') }}
    serviceAccounts:
      - email: default
        scopes:
        - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
        - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using DM, but... are you sure you want to run containers and at the same time install PHP on the host? If you're runnning containers, I'd rather add another container with PHP. It makes more sense.

Anyway, if you want to install PHP (and others) on host, you can use a metadata.startup-script (example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/metadata_from_file/jinja). As @fariya-rahmat mentioned - probably you want to use a different OS for it.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox):

You need to install additional packages or tools on Container-Optimized OS for certain tasks, such as debugging. Although Container-Optimized OS does not include a package manager, you can use the pre-installed [toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-toolbox) utility to install any additional packages
or tools you require. Using /usr/bin/toolbox is the preferred method for installing and running one-off debugging tools.

Container-Optimized OS does not include a package manager; as such, you'll be unable to install software packages directly on an instance. However, you can use [CoreOS toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox) to install and run debugging and admin tools in an isolated container.

Refer to the link [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits).